# Update TimeRecorded on edititemtemplate label vb.net

Tags: vb.net, edititemtemplate

I'm trying to have a label in the edititemtemplate of my gridview show the current date and time when the user clicks the edit linkbutton. When I put date.now in the data binding box, I can see the result I want, but when I click update, I get an error that the field can't be null. It works fine when I try it for the footer row, but not the edit row. Here's the footer row code that works:

```
'Get Time Recorded
Dim lblFtrTimeRecorded As Label = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblFtrTimeRecorded")
lblFtrTimeRecorded.Text = Date.Now
```

Here's the template field .aspx code:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TimeRecorded" SortExpression="TimeRecorded">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEditTimeRecorded" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("TimeRecorded") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFtrTimeRecorded" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimeRecorded" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("TimeRecorded") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Write this code :

```
Dim lblFtrTimeRecorded As Label = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("lblFtrTimeRecorded")
lblFtrTimeRecorded.Text = Date.Now
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this does not work. It errors on [GridView1.EditIndex] and also says lblFtrTimeRecorded isn't declared.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding, I'm fairly new to vb.net. Also I'm putting this in the page load, is that where it should go?

Comment: Give me Your Full Code